# Mathematical description of moving sofa problem

Tags: geometry, functions, analytic-geometry

Moving sofa problem asks what is the biggest area of a sofa that can be moved through L-shaped corridor. Now how can this problem be described in mathematical terms? So the sofa is basically any connected set of points but now how can we describe the movement of the sofa through a corridor in mathematical terms ? I thought of using isometries but one isometry can only describe the position of a sofa at some specific moment of movement. So how can we describe the movement of the sofa through a corridor in mathematical terms ?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1787466/458276.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MovingSofaProblem.html