# Question about the Solution to the Moving Sofa Problem

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, rotations

I have a question about the solution to this question posed by @newzad: [Modelling the "Moving Sofa"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787466/modelling-the-moving-sofa)

In the answer, @Intelligenti pauca solves the equation

$$ (x_{env}/r)^2+(y_{env}/t)^2=1 $$

where

$$ x_{env}=(r−t)\cosα+\frac12(t−r)\cos(2α)+\frac12(r+t) $$
$$ y_{env}=4(t−r)\sin\fracα2\cos^3\fracα2 $$

And obtains the solution

$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\bar\alpha=
2\arccos\sqrt{t\over{t+r}}, &\text{for $t\le3r$;}\\
\displaystyle\bar\alpha=
\arccos\sqrt{t\over{2(t-r)}}, &\text{for $t\ge3r$.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

I can't seem to solve the equation analytically, and was hoping someone could help me with it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think I largely used Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

Use the definition of $y_{\text{env}}$, plug in the first equation, make $\alpha=2 \cos ^{-1}(z)$. Now use the trigonometric identities, factor the result (since $z=\pm 1$ are trivial solutions) and what remains is
$$-4 t^3-4 z^2 \left(t^2 (3 r-5 t)\right)-32 z^4 \left(t^2 (t-r)\right)+z^6 (r-4 t)
   (r-t) (r+4 t)=0$$ which is a cubic equation in $z^2$.

Using the method for solving cubic equations (pretty tedious here), I suppose that we shall get the (nice and simple) result.

Comment: "trigonoùetric", ah ces satanés claviers!

Comment: @user3733558. French keyboard is not very comfortable for me (I am almost blind !). I can do worse ! By the way, where are you located (if I may ask) ? Cheers :-)

Comment: I was born and raised in south-east France, and I'm still a national. Though I've been living in german-speaking Switzerland for the past 30 years, I still have fond memories of making this exact same typo in my younger years ;)

Comment: @user3733558. I bet I am much older than you are (I am almost 80). Anyway, nice to meet you. Cheers :-)