# How do I find the equation of an envelope?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, envelope

I read that you must solve the two equations $$g(x,y,c)=0\\\frac{\partial g}{\partial c}=0$$
for $x$ and $y$ as a function of $c$, but how exactly do you go about doing this? The specific example I am trying to solve is where
$$F(x,y,\alpha)=
-t y \sin\alpha \tan{\alpha\over2} - t \sin\alpha 
\left(x - r \cos\alpha - t \sin\alpha \tan{\alpha\over2}\right)$$
and find the parametric equation for the envelope ($r$ and $t$ are constants). BTW, this is from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787466/modelling-the-moving-sofa) if you are curious.

Comment: One possible simplification here is to make the half-angle tangent substitution $s=\tan(\alpha/2)$. Then $\cos\alpha = (1-s^2)/(1+s^2)$ and $\sin\alpha=2s/(1+s^2)$, so now we have $G(x,y,s):=F(x,y,2\tan^{-1} s)$ as some rational function of $x,y,s$. (It's still not exactly nice but it may be easier to compute with.)

Comment: What is $t$? It does not appear as an argument to $F$.

Comment: @robjohn $t$ and $r$ are constants. Sorry for not being very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curves given by $F(x,y,\alpha)=0$, are also given by $G(x,y,u)=0$ where $u=\tan\left(\frac\alpha2\right)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
G(x,y,u)
&=\frac{F(x,y,\alpha)}{-t\sin(\alpha)}\tag{1a}\\
&=y\tan\left(\frac\alpha2\right)+\left(x-r\cos(\alpha)-t\sin(\alpha)\tan\left(\frac\alpha2\right)\right)\tag{1b}\\
&=yu+x-r\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}-t\frac{2u^2}{1+u^2}\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
Then, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\frac{2u^2}{1+u^2}=\frac{4u}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}$,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u}G(x,y,u)=y-(t-r)\frac{4u}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}G(x,y,u)=0$ when
$$
y=(t-r)\frac{4u}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}\tag3
$$
and then $G(x,y,u)=0$ when
$$
x=t+(r-t)\frac{1+4u^2-u^4}{\left(1+u^2\right)^2}\tag4
$$

---

**Example:** $r=2,t=1$

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.